# How to make pointer point to two or more consecutive cells

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have a `uint8_t` pointer point to the third element in an array, {1, 2, 4, 5} so `*p` is 4. How can I get it to point to 4 and 5 so that `*p` is 45. Is it even possible? I'm currently typecasting. Here's what I do e.g. if data is my array {1, 2, 4, 5} and I want to get 4 and 5.

```
uint8_t dummyAddress = data[2]; 
dummyAddress = *((uint16_t*) dummyAddress);
*p = *dummyAddress;
```

My understanding is that p should now point to 4 and 5 but I'm not. Instead I get a seg fault when I execute the second line.  p is a `uint64_t * const`. It works to get one byte, but when applying same logic to two bytes I'm not getting it right.

Comment: Please give complete code (Array declaration, types of the variables used, ...).

Comment: You should compile with a higher warning Level and listen to the Compiler warnings.

Comment: In your code `dummyAddress` is not a pointer

Comment: You could write `*p = data[2] + data[3] * 0x100;` or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
uint8_t data[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
uint8_t *p8 = &data[2];
uint16_t u16 = *(uint16_t*)p8;
```

Then `(uint16_t*)p8` will point to `data[2]` and `data[3]`. But you cannot easily access `*(uint16_t*)p8`. First this is because `p8` might not be aligned on `uint16_t` boundary. Some processor cause an exception in this case. Second, even if you can access `*(uint16_t*)p8` you might get different results depending on the processor's byte order (big endian/little endian). You might get 0x0405 or you might get 0x0504.

Please also note that in your line

```
dummyAddress = *((uint16_t*) dummyAddress);
```

you are first reinterpreting `dummyAddress` as a pointer to `uint16_t` and then dereferencing it, so returning a `uint16_t` and storing this in `dummyAddress`. This clearly is not what you wanted to do. If this really compiles, please consider compiling with a higher warning level and taking a look at every compiler warning (and only ignoring it if you understand it and are sure it is not a programming error).

BTW, you will not be able to get a pointer `p` where `*p==45` as you request in your question.

Also, as mch said: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: by default it seems to grab the bytes in little endian, so *p is 0x0504. now if I want to reverse it so *p reads 0x405 I'm confused about how to go about it. I've seen people use the << operator and shifting the bits 8 times or multiplying *p by 256 certain number of times? Any explanation please

Comment: Yes, you can do that with shifting like `uint16_t a = ...; uint16_t b = (a >> 8) | (a << 8)`. Of even better directly work on the data array `uint16_t b = ((uint16_t)data[2] << 8) | data[3]` (or exchange data[2] and data[3]).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing, then yes, you can access both bytes by casting to `uint16_t`, but you will run into problems (or endianess issues) with how the order the bytes are stored in memory as well as violate strict-aliasing. This will probably return an answer you were not suspecting. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void) {

    uint8_t array[] = {1,2,3,4};
    uint8_t *p = array + 2;

    printf ("\n the uint8_t answer  : %hhd\n", *p);
    printf (" the uint16_t answer : %hd\n\n", *(uint16_t *)p);

    printf ("**note: the will cast result in bytes 4, 3"
            " (or (4 << 8 | 3) = 1027)\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/cast_array

 the uint8_t answer  : 3
 the uint16_t answer : 1027

**note: the cast will result in bytes 4, 3 (or (4 << 8 | 3) = 1027)
```

The bytes are stored in memory on my system in `little endian` order. So when you cast to `uint16_t` it expects to find `least significant`, `most significant` bytes. Which in the example above with `34` in memory, the cast will interpret the actual order as `43` resulting in a value of `1027` instead of `(3 << 8) | 4 = 772`.

As noted, you will be violating rules related to *strict aliasing* where type pruning by casting to anything other than `char` results in undefined behavior. The results of all of these actions are hardware and compiler dependent and should not be used for anything other than a learning exercise.

Comment: `*(uint16_t *)p` invokes undefined behaviour, because it violates the strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
uint_8_t  *dummyAddress= &data[2];
uint_16_t *dummyAddress2= (uint16_t *) dummyAddress;

uint_16_t p= *dummyAddress2;
```

but note that due to "endianness" you may get the two `uint_8`'s in the wrong order, i.e. as `{data[3], data[2}`.

Comment: and it is undefined behaviour because it violates the strict aliasing rule.